# "error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1" when trying to run RStudio Connect

Tags: rstudio-server, libcrypto

I am trying to install RStudio Connect using these commands:

```
RPM_FILE='rstudio-connect-1.8.8.1.el8.x86_64.rpm'
curl -sO https://cdn.rstudio.com/connect/1.8.8/${RPM_FILE}
sudo yum install -y $RPM_FILE
```

Which works but when i try to do

```
sudo systemctl stop rstudio-connect
```

What could be wrong? Do i need to install some package (libcrypto?) or why is it complanining about that
I get these errors:

```
Error running license manager command '[verify]'; see system messages (syslog) for details: exit status 127
stdout:
stderr: /opt/rstudio-connect/bin/../ext/activation/license-manager: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021/05/17 11:17:36 Failed to update licensing; marking expired: exit status 127
2021/05/17 11:17:36 Server.Address is not configured. An address enables features that direct your users back to this server, such as email messages with links to your content.
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing a dependency.   Check if libcrypto is installed.

Comment: when i do sudo yum list installed, I can only find libcrypt.x86_64 - do i need something else?

Comment: I have already done sudo yum install openssl-devel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I was installing the wrong version (for Centos 8 instead of 7)...

It should have been

```
curl -O https://cdn.rstudio.com/connect/1.8.8/rstudio-connect 1.8.8.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install rstudio-connect-1.8.8.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu based you can install libssl with next command:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```